# BufferedReader issue - doesn't respond properly

Tags: java

I found this TCP server online, I want to modify it a little bit to return different message than was typed in the client. It doesn't work as I want; the `else {}` works "like a charm" but the first if doesn't - the client is still waiting for input.

server.java

```
while(true)
{
Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
String test="hey";
String tempus="tster";
if(clientSentence.contains(test)==true){
System.out.println(tempus);
outToClient.writeBytes(tempus);
}
else{
capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
}
```

client.java

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
{
String sentence;
String modifiedSentence;
BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
clientSocket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common mistake when read/writing to files/socket is to mix and match text with binary and get horribly confused.  You have used both.

You need to use text or binary, it appears you want to use text. e.g. BufferedReader and PrintWriter. (note: PrintWriter silently consumes exceptions in the underlying stream)

Answer (score 0):

In the `BufferedReader` you wait for a line, which is indicated by the `\n` in the end, as you did in the `else`. If you want to use readLine, you need to send a line (which ends with the new line character - `\n`.

If you don't want to append a new line character at the end of the input, you can use the [`BufferedReader#read(char[],int,int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method

Answer (score 0):

the BufferedReader.readLine() is trying to read an entire line of input (i.e. it's looking for the newline character '\n'). Your string in the "else" block appends the newline at the end whereas your `tempus` variable is not terminated with a newline so the client just waits.